# Pandas: Find weekly max from timeseries(calendar week not 7 days)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want my dataframe to be grouped by calendar weekly, like Monday to Sunday.

```
timestamp           value
# before time
...
# this is a Friday
2021-10-01 13:00:00 2204.0
2021-10-01 13:30:00 3262.0
...
# this is next Monday
2021-10-04 16:00:00 254.0
2021-10-04 16:30:00 990.0
2021-10-04 17:00:00 1044.0
2021-10-04 17:30:00 26.0
...
# time continues
```

The result I'm expecting, hope this is clear enough.

```
timestamp           value   weekly_max
# this is a Friday
2021-10-01 13:00:00 2204.0  3262.0 # assume 3262.0 is the maximum value during 2021-09-27 to 2021-10-03
2021-10-01 13:30:00 3262.0  3262.0
...
# this is next Monday
2021-10-04 16:00:00 254.0   1044.0
2021-10-04 16:30:00 990.0   1044.0
2021-10-04 17:00:00 1044.0  1044.0
2021-10-04 17:30:00 26.0    1044.0
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get week number:

```
df['week'] = df.datetime.dt.isocalendar().week
```

get max for each week

```
df_weeklymax = df.groupby('week').agg(max=('value', 'max')).reset_index()
```

merge 2 tables

```
df.merge(df_weeklymax, on='week', how='left')
```

example output:

|  | datetime | value | week | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 20 | 53 | 69 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 13:36:00 | 69 | 53 | 69 |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 03:12:00 | 69 | 53 | 69 |
| 3 | 2021-01-02 16:48:00 | 57 | 53 | 69 |
| 4 | 2021-01-03 06:24:00 | 39 | 53 | 69 |
| 5 | 2021-01-03 20:00:00 | 56 | 53 | 69 |
| 6 | 2021-01-04 09:36:00 | 73 | 1 | 92 |
| 7 | 2021-01-04 23:12:00 | 76 | 1 | 92 |
| 8 | 2021-01-05 12:48:00 | 92 | 1 | 92 |
| 9 | 2021-01-06 02:24:00 | 4 | 1 | 92 |